# Making a knife for brit Mila ( with a shinui or goy) on shabbat

Tags: shabbat, brit-milah

Can someone please remind me where the machloket is regarding wether making a knife for a brit Milah on shabbat is mutar or assur. Another thing, I know we pasken its assur however if someone was to make it using a shinui or even better asking a goy to do it would it be mutar even with the de'ah that we pasken with?

Answer (score 2):

As to your first question -- it's the [19th chapter of Tractate Shabbat](http://www.come-and-hear.com/shabbath/shabbath_130.html#chapter_xix) (starting on [page 130](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2119.htm)); known as "Rabbi Eliezer d'Milah."